# error occurring while using 'twython'

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

I want to fetch tweets based on hashtags. But I get the below error.

```
>>> import twython
>>> TWITTER_APP_KEY = 'xxxxxx'
>>> TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
>>> TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxx'
>>> TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
>>> t = twython(app_key=TWITTER_APP_KEY, 
        app_secret=TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET, 
            oauth_token=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
            oauth_token_secret=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 4, in <module>
    oauth_token_secret=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I do not understand why the above error occurs? Also please let me know if app_key is the same as consumer key?
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython#usage):

```
from twython import Twython

t = Twython(app_key=app_key,
            app_secret=app_secret,
            callback_url='http://google.com/')
```

In your example, you call the **module** `twython` directly instead of the class `twyton.Twython`.

To make your example work you need to replace `import twython` with `from twython import Twython`.